# displaying a text file in a table cell

Tags: javascript

I want to put a text file into a table cell like below:

```
                   <td>

                            <script>
                            var t = new Date();
                            var m = t.getMonth()+1;
                            var d = t.getDate();

                            mm = m.toString();
                            dd = d.toString();

                            var f = mm + dd + ".txt";

                            window.location.href = f; 

                            </script>

                    </td>
```

Only that text file is displayed however.  The rest of the webpage isn't shown.  i'm guessing it's the "window.location.href = f;" line.  What shoud I do instead?

Comment: If you want to read the file and put content into page, check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of options.

1. Put the content there using a server side technology
2. Use [an iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)
3. Use [the XMLHttpRequest object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) to fetch the data and then DOM to [generate a text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode) and [append it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) to the table cell

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use IFRAME:

```
<td>

   <iframe id="ifr" ></iframe>

   <script>
    var t = new Date();
    var m = t.getMonth()+1;
    var d = t.getDate();

    mm = m.toString();
    dd = d.toString();

    var f = mm + dd + ".txt";

    document.getElementById('ifr').src = f; 

    </script>

</td>
```

You can style the iframe to give width and height as needed.